# Stripe and NodeJS - Passing an amount to charge

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

**EDIT:** To clarify, the charge does actually process, the only thing I can't do is dynamically set the charge amount.

I've worked all day and haven't found any solution. Here is my server.js:

```
app.post('/charge', function(req, res) {
var stripeToken = req.body.stripeToken;
var amount = 12000;
console.log(req);
stripe.charges.create({
    card: stripeToken,
    currency: 'usd',
    amount: amount
},
function(err, charge) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(500, err);
    } else {

        res.send(204);
    }
});
});
```

And here is my dynamic stripe button.

```
$('#calcTransAmount').click(function(event) {
var amount = $('#transAmount').scope().totall;
//console.log(amount);
var holder = document.getElementById('hello');
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js';
script.setAttribute('class', 'stripe-button');
script.setAttribute('data-amount', amount);
script.setAttribute('data-key',"KEY");
script.setAttribute('data-image', "IMG");
script.setAttribute('data-name', "NAME");
script.setAttribute('data-billing-address', "true");
script.setAttribute('data-description', "Purchase");
script.setAttribute('data-locale', "auto");
document.getElementById('btnCont').appendChild(script);
});
```

The button works with the dynamic amount and everything, now I just can't seem to figure out how the post to `/charge` receives the amount and sets it as a variable.

This is my `req` object:

```
{ stripeToken: 'tok_19t9jcLhf04QCVXXXXXXXX',
 stripeTokenType: 'card',
 stripeEmail: 'me@gmail.com',
 stripeBillingName: 'Clark',
 stripeBillingAddressCountry: 'United States',
 stripeBillingAddressCountryCode: 'US',
 stripeBillingAddressZip: 'Zip',
 stripeBillingAddressLine1: 'My address',
 stripeBillingAddressCity: 'City',
 stripeBillingAddressState: 'State' }
```

And I can't find a way to get my data-amount attribute from the button to the server to charge a dynamic amount.

Thanks

Comment: The issue here is that you really don't want the amount to come from the client. Anyone can change the amount and then pay $1 instead of $99 for the order. The amount has to be known server-side, based on what the customer is ordering for security reasons.

Comment: That is an excellent point actually! Thank you! So my follow-up question to that would be, is there a way to pass a custom variable through the Stripe button to my server side that will allow the server to lookup the cart in our DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to *@koopajah* for the inspiration for the solution.

In the form on the client side, in addition to the javascript button, I passed a key value using a hidden input box that would allow my server side to grab the cart total from our DB.

```
<form action="/charge" method="POST"> 
    <input name="coKey" value ="{{currentUser.coKey}}">
</form>
```

Then on the server side, I can pull the appropriate key like this: `var coKey = req.body.coKey;`